# Monodroid Visual Studio Android App Not Copying to device

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, android-emulator, xamarin.android

Hi I am new to the Android Application world.  I have installed the Monodroid plugin for Visual Studio.  I created a new Mono for Android Application.  The project builds, I start my emulator,  I select my emulator in the Select Devices dialog, the dialog then states Copying application to device...   the dialog then goes away.  However, the application never appears in my emulator.  There are no errors the project builds fine, but the app never appears in the emulator.  has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the app is starting and crashing quickly.  Check the Android Debug Log to see if there are any exceptions or messages there.

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Comment: Does this make sense to anyone? Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{41491b30 com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_POLL}

Comment: Or this java.lang.IllegalStateException